# convert recursion to (for,while)loop

Tags: java

i need help to convert this recursion method to any loop because it's give this Exception `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
public static long Q(long a,long b,long q){
    if(q==1){
        return a;
    }
    if(q==2){
        return b;
    }
    else{
        return Q(a,b,q-1)^Q(a,b,q-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this method `Q`. What should it calculate based on the arguments `a`, `b` and `q`?

Comment: it's just way to find the xor between `a ,b` using  `q `
maybe you can understand it clearly from this https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/223338/problem/D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need any loops to calculate the result. When you write the first values for `Q(...)` you will see a pattern, where the same term get cancelled out as you will run something like `Q(x) ^ Q(x)` at some point, which results in `0`. Check the following list of `Q(...)` for the first numbers:

```
Q(1) = a
Q(2) = b
Q(3) = Q(2) ^ Q(1)          = a^b
Q(4) = Q(3) ^ Q(2)
     = Q(2) ^ Q(1) ^ Q(2)
     = Q(1)                 = a
Q(5) = Q(4) ^ Q(3)
     = Q(1) ^ Q(2) ^ Q(1)
     = Q(2)                 = b
Q(6) = Q(5) ^ Q(4)
     = Q(2) ^ Q(1)          = a^b
Q(7) = Q(6) ^ Q(5)
     = Q(2) ^ Q(1) ^ Q(2)
     = Q(1)                 = a
Q(8) = Q(7) ^ Q(6)
     = Q(1) ^ Q(2) ^ Q(1)
     = Q(2)                 = b
Q(9) = Q(8) ^ Q(7)
     = Q(2) ^ Q(1)          = a^b
```

As you see the value is iterating between `a`, `b` and `a^b`. So you can use a simple modulo check on `q` to get the correct value:

```
public static long Q(long a,long b,long q){
    long modulo = q%3;
    if (modulo == 0) {
        return a^b;
    }
    if (modulo == 1) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```